# Why I got segmentation fault when using fgets in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, fgets

I run the program with this command:

```
./word_search oi < text.txt
```

and got **segmentation fault** when running it.

This program is aiming to find where the word (giving as command line arg) exists in a file and print out those lines.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "substring.c"

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    if(argc == 2) {
        char *str;
        while(fgets(str, 100, stdin)) {
            if(substring(str, argv[1]) != -1) {
                printf("Found: %s", str);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I change `char *str` into `char str[100]` then it works pretty good. Could anyone please tell me why?
The contents in `substring.c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int substring(const char *line, const char *substr) {
    int i, j;
    int result;
    for(i = 0; i <= strlen(line)-strlen(substr); i++) {
        result = 0;
        if(line[i] == substr[0]) {
            int c = i;
            for(j = 0; j < strlen(substr); j++) {
                if (line[c] != substr[j]) {
                    result = -1;
                }
                c++;
            }
            if(result != -1)
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```

The contents in `test.txt` are just several lines of meaningless characters.

Comment: You have a pointer `str`, but *where does it point?* The `fgets` function can't allocate memory for you, you need to make sure you have an array to pass to `fgets`, or allocate memory yourself and make `str` point to it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post text as image.

Comment: None of the nearly 400 results for a search here for [c segmentation fault fgets](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+segmentation+fault+fgets) helps you solve this problem?

Comment: You should enable warnings in your compiler. For GCC you could use `-Wall -Wpedantic`. This might give you some warning about using variable `str` without initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *str` is an unitialized pointer, it cannot hold the string you are trying to copy into it, either allocate memory to it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 100

char *str = malloc(SIZE); //char has the size of 1 across platforms
```

Or simply declare it with the size you need:

```
char str[SIZE];
```

Pass the size of str to `fgets`

```
while(fgets(str, SIZE, stdin))
```

Of `fgets`:

- Your container will be null terminated, it can only hold a string of `SIZE - 1` characters.
- All characters above `SIZE - 1`, including `'\n'` will remain unread and therefore in the buffer, you might need to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take some time to learn basic C. Especially read about pointers, they are bit hard to get right at first.

In your example, str is a pointer to an undefined memory location.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified that.